# Michelson interferometer with monochromatic light

Tags: spectroscopy, interferometry

I have a "simple" question: is it possible to see, in a Michelson interferometer, interference fringes with a monochromatic source of light? I have this doubt because I've seen that the Fourier transform of the interference fringes (the one like Airy-disk), that correspond in time-domain to a function like $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is a "Box", like in the image; but if the source is monochromatic, where do the new frequencies come from?

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding your post, but those curves are graphs of intensity of the light project onto a surface. They have nothing to do with the frequencies that the light itself carries. To say it another way, consider light projected onto a wall/screen. If the x-,y-axes are in the plane of the wall, and the z-axis is perpendicular to the wall, then those intensity patterns concern the distribution of light across the x, y-directions. The frequency/color of light concerns the distribution of light across the z-axis (direction of propagation of light).

Comment: Maybe can you rephrase your question to be more clear? Why do you think there should be new frequencies?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal My bad, thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Any finite signal has a frequency width and is not absolutely monochromatic.  As soon as we make a finite measurement, which corresponds to a fourier transform with an envelope, we obtain a broadened spectrum. This is very easy to check using a basic fourier integral

$$
\tilde E(\omega)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}  E(t)\exp(-i\omega t)dt
$$
Note that the integration is from negative to positive infinity. But no real measurement is carried out for that long. We can include the finiteness of our signal/measurement by including a box function in the definition of our signal
$$
E(t) = \exp(i\omega_0t)\Theta(t;T)\\
\Theta(t;T) \cases{ 1 : |t|<T\\
0 : |t| >T }
$$
This correspond to a finite measurement of a  monochromatic wave for a duration of $2T$.
Inserting this into the integral yields
$$\begin{aligned}
\tilde E(\omega) &= \int^\infty_{-\infty}\exp(i\omega_0t)\Theta(t;T)\exp(-i\omega t) dt\\
&=\int^T_{-T}\exp(i\omega_0t)\exp(-i\omega t) dt\\
&=\int^T_{-T}\exp(i(\omega_0-\omega)t)dt\\ 
&=\frac{1}{i(\omega_0-\omega)}[\exp(i(\omega_0-\omega)t)]^T_{-T}\\
\tilde E(\omega)&=\cases{2\frac{\sin((\omega-\omega_0)T)}{(\omega_0-\omega)} : \omega \neq \omega_0 \\
2T: \omega = \omega_0}
\end{aligned}$$

We obtain a sinc function  in the frequency domain centered on the central frequency $\omega_0$.

Monochromatic waves are mathematically useful, but they are an idealized limit that is experimentally impossible to realize. Even when we speak of monochromatic light sources, it is still basically a light pulse with a very long envelope with a large value for $T$ such that the width of the spectrum is smaller than our required resolution. The spectrum of a real monochromatic wave is thus not exactly a single peak at one frequency. This is not directly tied to Michelson-Interferometry but a general fact whenever you have a Fourier transform of a finite signal.